# can we update mutable datatypes(like list) inside function without global keyword in python?

Tags: python, types, global

If yes so can we conclude that in python we can update mutable datatypes anywhere inside program without `global` keyword and we cannot update immutable datatypes without `global` keyword?

Comment: `global` **has nothing to do with mutating objects**. It's for changing the *scope of variables*. Also, very importantly, you *can't update immutable types anywhere because they are immutable*. That is what immutable means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ever modify an immutable object, with or without the `global` keyword. You can use `global` to reassign a *variable* that's in an outer scope, but that's not the same thing as modifying the *object* that the variable points to.

```
foo = 5
bar = foo

def update_foo():
    global foo
    foo += 3

print(foo, bar)  # 5 5
update_foo()
print(foo, bar)  # 8 5
```

In the above example, we use `global` to reassign the `foo` variable in the outer scope, but the actual object that `foo` points to remains unchanged, which is why `bar` retains the value `5`.

Compare this to what happens when we mutate a mutable object, like a list:

```
foo = [5]
bar = foo

def update_foo():
    # "global foo" has no effect one way or the other here
    foo[0] += 3

print(foo, bar)  # [5] [5]
update_foo()
print(foo, bar)  # [8] [8]
```

Note that `global foo` wouldn't do anything here because we're not reassigning the *variable* `foo`, we're instead modifying the *object* that it points to (and this is something that's only possible with mutable objects -- you'll get an error if you try to do `foo[0] += 3` on a tuple, because tuples are immutable).

If we reassign the *variable* `foo`:

```
foo = [5]
bar = foo

def update_foo():
    global foo
    foo = [foo[0] + 3]

print(foo, bar)  # [5] [5]
update_foo()
print(foo, bar)  # [8] [5]
```

then the behavior with the list is the same as it is with the int, because we haven't actually modified the underlying object, just reassigned one of the variables to point to an entirely new object.

Obligatory link: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

`global` keyword pertains to the scope of a variable, not mutability.
`global` is used to make a locally assigned variable available globally.